# How to calculate available vacation days?

Tags: c#

I need to calculate number of vacation days of employee.
For example, he is working from `2020-05-13` to `2020-08-26`.

- If his first work day was from 1 to 15 - he gets 2 vacation days;
- From 15 to 25 - 1 day;
- From 26 to 31 - 0 days.

He get's 2 vacation days in the begining of each month.

And he could be on vacations on this period, so I need to decreace this value from general number of his vacation days.

There is a table with working (1) and vacation (3) days. I need to use it to calculate, how much days of vacation left.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? The calculation algorithm? The ```TimeSpan``` or ```DateTime``` data types? Show us your code.

Comment: @DC_AC Yes, the algorithm. Should I calculate the number of months, then get first motht, check if it 2, 1 or 0 days.. or do it in another way

Comment: That seems the way to go. Get total vacation days: ```2*(#months-1) + GetFirstMonthVacationDays(startingDay)```. Then check with your table how many are already taken and subtract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will a good place to start, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1